# Angular 14 add interceptor to main.ts

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I just created a new Angular 14 project and I don't know where to include an interceptor for all http calls, as I did till version 13 into app.module. I tried this in main.ts, but it doesn't functions:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: StateService, useClass: StateService },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    importProvidersFrom(RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES), BrowserAnimationsModule)
  ]
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Any idea to do it? thanks

This is my interceptor file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { StateService } from './state.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  responseClone: any;

  constructor(private stateService: StateService) { console.log('AppInterceptor'); }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (this.stateService.accessToken) {
      this.responseClone = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.stateService.accessToken) });
      console.log('http interceptado:', this.responseClone.headers);
      return next.handle(this.responseClone);
    } else {
      console.log('http no interceptado');
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your AppInterceptor code please?

Comment: This inteceptor functions perfectly when I work with Angular modules, the problem is just now with version 14 without modules.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `HttpClientModule` to `importProvidersFrom` function.

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: StateService, useClass: StateService },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    importProvidersFrom([RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES), BrowserAnimationsModule,HttpClientModule])
  ]
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work. Maybe this version 14 is still not complete for working without ngModule at all.

Comment: Can you add Console log inside interceptor and check whether it's being printed or not?

Comment: As you can see in my interceptor code at the top of the post, I added three console.log, one even in the constructor, but there is no response. But I have detected the following: when I send a http call from a component at the same level than app.component, the interceptor does function perfectly, but if the component which made the call is inside a folder, the injector doesn't detect http calls. It's something weird, cause the injector is a service provided in root and it's add as provider in main.ts file.

Comment: I have tried in stackblitz after proving httpclientmodule in main ts it's working

Comment: Ok you're right, but only if the http call is made from a component at the same level than appcomponent. But interceptor doesn't function if the call is made from a component which is inside a folder or subfolder. I don't understand anything.